# backtrader shows same time for all candles

Tags: python, trading, backtrader, candlesticks

This is my code:

```
data15 = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname='BTCUSDT-15m-2022-01-01.csv',
dtformat=lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(x)/1000))
```

from csvgeneric.py:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(dtfield, dtformat)
    else:
        dt = self._dtconvert(dtfield)

    if self.p.timeframe >= TimeFrame.Days:
        # check if the expected end of session is larger than parsed
        if self._tzinput:
            dtin = self._tzinput.localize(dt)  # pytz compatible-ized
        else:
            dtin = dt

        dtnum = date2num(dtin)  # utc'ize

        dteos = datetime.combine(dt.date(), self.p.sessionend)
        dteosnum = self.date2num(dteos)  # utc'ize

        if dteosnum > dtnum:
            self.lines.datetime[0] = dteosnum
```

I see that for each candle, `dt, dtin and dtnum` are correct. `dteosnum` is the same all the time, and larger than `dtnum`, so `dteosnum` is the one assigned to the next candle (`self.lines.datetime[0]`).

So all candles get the same time.

Comment: For dtnum you call date2num: `dtnum = date2num(dtin)`, as for dteosnum you call self.date2num: `dteosnum = self.date2num(dteos)`. It is supposed to be like that?

Comment: @A.Herlas This is the library's code. Anyway I debugged the implementation of self.date2num and eventually it also calls date2num().